# How to calculate odds ratio with beta value in R

Tags: r, beta

Say I want to calculate odds ratio with beta value Beta=0.9. How do I write R code to get OR as shown in the formula below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# beta = 0.9

OR <- exp(0.9)
OR

# [1] 2.459603
```